# How to match string in single or double quoted using regex

Tags: regex, quotes

I'm trying to write a regex that matches strings as the following:

`translate("some text here")`

and

`translate('some text here')`

I've done that:

```html
preg_match ('/translate\("(.*?)"\)*/', $line, $m)
```

but how to add if there are single quotes, not double. It should match as single, as double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could go for:

```
translate\( # translate( literally
(['"])      # capture a single/double quote to group 1
.+?         # match anything except a newline lazily
\1          # up to the formerly captured quote
\)          # and a closing parenthesis
```

See a demo for [**this approach on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/nL9jG3/2).

---

In `PHP` this would be:

```
<?php

$regex = '~
            translate\( # translate( literally
            ([\'"])     # capture a single/double quote to group 1
            .+?         # match anything except a newline lazily
            \1          # up to the formerly captured quote
            \)          # and a closing parenthesis
         ~x';

if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    // do sth. here
}
?>
```

*Note* that you do not need to escape both of the quotes in square brackets (`[]`), I have only done it for the Stackoverflow prettifier.
Bear in mind though, that this is rather error-prone (what about whitespaces, escaped quotes ?).

---

In the comments the discussion came up that you cannot say **anything BUT the first captured group**. Well, yes, you can (thanks to Obama here), the technique is called a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) which can be achieved via lookarounds. Consider the following code:

```
translate\(
(['"])
(?:(?!\1).)*
\1
\)
```

It opens a non-capturing group with a **negative lookahead** that makes sure not to match the formerly captured group (a quote in this example).
This eradicates matches like  `translate("a"b"c"d")` (see [a demo here](https://regex101.com/r/nL9jG3/3)).

---

The final expression to [**match all given examples**](https://regex101.com/r/nL9jG3/6) is:

```
translate\(
(['"])
(?:
   .*?(?=\1\))
)
\1
\)
```

Comment: Thank you all! I don't know what is proper way, I'll try it.

Comment: `you do not need to escape the quotes in square brackets` actually you must, or your php parser will die.

Comment: @vp_arth: You are right and as you can see I did it in my code example. I meant you do not need to escape **both** of the quotes.

Comment: It still has false matches with like `translate("a"b"c"d")`. And my code fails here too :( It's because `.` matches quote, but there is not a way to declare `[^\1]` character class

Comment: So, I can to modify my answer with this. Your one now fails on correctly escaped quotes, like `translate("a\"b\"c\"d")` ;)

Comment: @vp_arth: I am accepting new challenges, see the updated answer at the bottom :)

Comment: Easy :) `translate("(\")")`

Comment: Also, `translate("a\"b"c\"d")` should not match, because unescaped quote inside.

Answer (score 2):

```
@translate\(
([\'"])      # capture quote char
((?:
  (?!\1).    # not a quote
|            # or
  \\\1       # escaped one
)* # 
[^\\\\]?)\1    # match unescaped last quote char
\)@gx
```

[Fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/nL9jG3/5):

```
ok: translate("some text here")
ok: translate('some text here')
ok: translate('"some text here..."')
ok: translate("a\"b\"c\"d")
ok: translate("")
no: translate("a\"b"c\"d")
```

Comment: Upvoted yours but see my updated answer at the bottom (new challenges are more then welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can alternate expression components using the pipe (|) like this:

```
preg_match ('/translate(\("(.*?)"\)|\(\'(.*?)\'\))/', $line, $m)
```

Edit: previous also matched `translate("some text here')`. This should work but you will have to escape the quotes in some languages.

Comment: `translate("some text here')` Also you must to escape quotes in php strings.

Comment: Will it find both matches - when I have - translate('text') and translate("text")?

Comment: Yes but as @vp_arth said it will also match `translate("some text here')` I'll edit it so that it should work

Comment: There is a way, but it is not very smart -> if(preg_match ('/translate\("(.*?)"\)*/', $line, $m) || preg_match ("/translate\('(.*?)'\)*/", $line, $m)) {

Comment: in js this will works well: `/([\"'])(?:\\\1|.)*?\1/`. May be somebody can to translate it to php?